# Rails member routing, should be easy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes, member

For this route:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    resources :stakeholders
  end
end
```

The generated routes are:

```
    projects_stakeholders GET    /projects/projects/:id/stakeholders(.:format)                                                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"projects/stakeholders"}
                          POST   /projects/projects/:id/stakeholders(.:format)                                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"projects/stakeholders"}
    new_projects_stakeholder GET    /projects/projects/:id/stakeholders/new(.:format)                                              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"projects/stakeholders"}
    edit_projects_stakeholder GET    /projects/projects/:id/stakeholders/:id/edit(.:format)                                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects/stakeholders"}
projects_stakeholder GET    /projects/projects/:id/stakeholders/:id(.:format)                                              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects/stakeholders"}
```

As these routes have two times a :id parameter, if I have, for instance the URL 'projects/4/stakeholders/11'

In my log file I see this:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
```

How can I then access my project_id from inside my controller?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `member do` block around it. Just do this, and you should start seeing a `project_id` in your params:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :stakeholders
end
```

Comment: Even simpler than I thought... Thanks! Does that mean that I should only use "member do" when I want to add an action to my controller?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to add an action to a specific `project` object, you would use `member` route.